# is there a faster way to make this code faster?

Tags: algorithm

So we were tasked to make the code below faster, as there are examples for the code where it will need an input of very large strings, any help will do.

```py
w = input()
e = input()

aasd = ''
i = 0

for i in range(len(w)):
    elif e[i] in w:
        aasd = aasd + 'b'
    i = i + 1

print(aasd)
```

Comment: Engaging in an *edit war* is unwise. Generally, if code worked/was syntactically correct before editing, keep it that way in your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most expensive operation here seems `elif b[i] in a` (having complexity `O(len(a))`, since string lookup isn't optimised like a set. You can create a set of characters in `a` to make the lookup faster.

```py
import sys

z = int(input())
a = input()
set_a = set(a)
b = input()

strs = ''

for i in range(z):
    if b[i] == a[i]:
        strs = strs + 'a'
    elif b[i] in set_a:
        strs = strs + 'b'
    else:
        strs = strs + 'c'

sys.stdout.write(strs)
```

Comment: It is not needed to call `list` on `a`. A string is iterable.

Comment: @trincot good catch

Comment: Please note, that this code could fail if `z` is bigger than any of the arrays as the index would be out of bounds. Same holds true if `z` was set to length of `a` but array `b` is shorter than a, and of course the other way round.

Comment: @Mushroomator OP hasn't requested to debug the code. A speedup was the only prerequisite here, which has been provided

Comment: @AbhinavMathur true. Nevertheless, I think it is good to give a beginner some hints on what other problems there are with his code, that's all I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

The following function will do the job with the key change being using a [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/set.html) instead of a list which will decrease the runtime from `O(len(a) * len(b))` to `O(len(a))`.

Some other changes are some checks on array length which you need to do to be sure your index will not be out of bounds of the array.

```py
import sys

# what do you need z for?
# this will only cause problems, you can use len() instead to get the lenght of the string
# z = int(input())
a = input("Please enter string a: ")
b = input("Please enter string b: ")


def compare_strs(a, b):
    strs = ''
    # no need for this here as range will start at 0 by default
    # i = 0
    # set will have constant lookup time O(1)
    lookupCharacters = set(a)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        # you need to make sure the index is in bounds of the array here!
        if i < len(b):
            if b[i] == a[i]:
                strs = strs + 'a'
            # this will now lookup in the set which takes O(1) and not O(len(a))
            elif b[i] in lookupCharacters:
                strs = strs + 'b'
        strs = strs + 'c'
        # no need for this here as range() will automatically increase i for the next iteration
        # i = i + 1
    sys.stdout.write(strs)


compare_strs(a, b)
```

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo here. Obviously meant to use `lookupCharacters` instead of `a`. Updated my answer.